# Which Eclipse package to install for Java/Python?

Tags: java, python-3.x, eclipse

I want to download/install an Eclipse IDE for Java/Python, but the Eclipse website doesn't indicate which package is suitable for PyDev. Which one should I download/install?

Also, if I need to do Javascript, CSS, HTML or PHP programming, will I need to download/install separate Eclipse IDEs?

Here are the different packages:
[Eclipse Packages Website](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/)

[image: Package List (1)]

[image: Package List (2)]

[image: Package List (3)]

Comment: And just for the record: when you are *new* to eclipse ... consider for a second to not do that. I always found the python plugins within eclipse to be slow and clunky. At some point I tried the standalone PyCharm instead. Guess what: it worked much better. So good, that I later switched to Intellij; the Java IDE from the makers of PyCharm. Honestly: using pycharm + intellij very much beats eclipse with python plugins for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the packages page there's a link (easily overlooked, unfortunately) labeled **[Compare & Combine Packages](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/compare)**. That page basically answers your question:

> These packages are provided as a convenience to users; they represent common configurations of Eclipse projects that are often used together. However, since Eclipse is, at its core, an expandable platform, you can easily add other features and plugins to any of these packages. Just choose and install the package that most closely meets your needs, then follow [these instructions](http://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-124.htm) to add features that you need.

Comment: Just compared them and notice that some checkmarks are blue and some are orange. Blue means 'included' and orange means 'included (with source)'. What is the difference?

Comment: I guess that means you probably get the source code of the plugins packaged with eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not meant to point a specific offsite resource, but the *principle* that comes to play here: using eclipse plugins to add a support for a specific language/feature!

First of all, there is no predefined eclipse build for python.

You can simply install the "Java developer" one and then manually add python support via the eclipse [marketplace](https://www.eclipse.org/mpc/), for example by installing the [pydev](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pydev-python-ide-eclipse) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can go ahead with **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers**.

Once it is installed you can go to Help->Install New Software and can install all other plugins as per your requirements.

For example to install Python use the following [Link](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/handouts/pythoneclipsejava/eclipsepython%20oxygen.html).